# Why getByEmail returns 404 not found?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api, getmethod

I have the folowing controller and route

```
   [HttpGet]
        [Route("getByEmail/{email:alpha}")]
        public IHttpActionResult Get(string email)
        {
            var user = _userLogic.GetUserByEmail(email);
            return Ok(user);
        }
```

But when I call

```
localhost/WebApp/api/user/getByEmail/fsd@sd
```

It return 404 not found

```
I've tried 
localhost/WebApp/api/user/getByEmail/?email=fsd@sd
```

But it goes to get all
Could someone please help me?

Comment: Need a lot more info.  What type email server?  It looks like you need an api installed in you webbrowser.

Comment: From [attribute-routing-in-web-api-2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) alpha matches uppercase or lowercase Latin alphabet characters (a-z, A-Z)

Answer (score 5):

It's likely because of your defined [route constraint](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints) of `:alpha` which requires that your parameter matches only uppercase and lowercase characters.

Since you are going to be passing in a `@`, this would cause the route to not properly be matched and thus you would receive the 404 error.

Simply remove the constraint and it should work as expected :

```
[Route("getByEmail/{email}")]
```

Comment: I would tend to validate the email with a regex however.

Comment: @Rion Williams ..And what route to put instead alpha?

Comment: @gretro If you did want to do something like that, you could define a custom route constraint (either using a regular expression or some other mechanism). However, validation and routing are generally going to be two different things.

Comment: @IoanAdrianDuliba You don't have to have a route constraint. Using `{email}` will automatically assume a string, which should be valid in your case.